# Ksh not found excution return value

Tags: python, system, executable, ksh, return-code

I was using Sqlmap for pen-testing my site `sqlmap.py` until the program stop suddenly and when I try to give it an option `--dbs` it gives me

```
[2] 16403 ksh: --dbs: not found
sqlmap.py -u mysite.com/contact.php?id=1 --dbs
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `&` character in the *real* URL you used. Quote the URL on your command line:

```
sqlmap.py -u "mysite.com/contact.php?id=1" --dbs
```

The `&` character puts a command in the background and the shell starts parsing from there for a new command.